# How is robustness measured in history and archaeology?

Tags: ancient-history, archaeology, prehistory

In physics and medicine there is quite a consensus of various levels of evidence. For example, physics has a scale of fifteen levels of scientific evidence ([DOI:Opera Magistris pg 50](https://DOI%2010.5281/zenodo.5816819,%20ISBN%20978-2-8399-0932-7%20(4th%20Edition))) and medicine has a scale of six to seven levels of scientific evidence (the higher the value of the evidence, the more we are confident on the conclusion). These scales are used to teach graduate students critical thinking about the scientific method and learn them how confident we can be to reject or accept a given claim or scientific paper.

I wasn't able to find any scale of that type in History and Archaeology.

Do you have any reference where I can find the scale of evidence that makes consensus in the field of History and Archaeology?

For example a significant percentage of young people and adults have difficulty making the difference between, for example:

- A visual testimony from a single person and a meta-analysis
- A primary source, a secondary source, a tertiary source
- An account in a document written by a copyist of an original document
- An opinion from a historian of a meta-analysis
- A meta-analysis and systematic review
- A blog of an article located in a peer-reviewed scientific journal in a high impact factor journal
- etc…

Comment: Source for needed for "physics has a scale of fifteen levels of scientific evidence"

Comment: "medicine has a scale of six to seven levels of scientific evidence" should probably read "several scales for levels of evidence have been proposed for usage in the health sector"? My understanding of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_of_evidence

Comment: Please revise the title to ask a question.   I _suspect_ that the answer is that confidence in physics and medicine you're measuring against the population, while in history and archaeology you're measuring against the sample size.  I think the question needs to be defined a bit more precisely, and  [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: For example a significant percentage of young people and adults have difficulty making the difference between, for example:

• A visual testimony from a single person and a meta-analysis
• A primary source, a secondary source, a tertiary source
• An account in a document written by a copyist of an original document
• An opinion from a historian of a meta-analysis
• A meta-analysis and systematic review
• A blog of an article located in a peer-reviewed scientific journal in a high impact factor journal
• etc…

Comment: @Jan Yes thanks for reformulating. That's better to say: "Several scales for levels of evidence have been proposed for usage in the health sector".

Comment: Source for needed for "physics has a scale of fifteen levels of scientific evidence" is: DOI 10.5281/zenodo.5816819, ISBN 978-2-8399-0932-7 (4th Edition)

Comment: @VincentISOZ I believe title and author would be more helpful here.

Comment: There is not one author but more than 800 co-authors.

Comment: @VincentISOZ Is there a title?

Comment: The title is "Opera Magistris"

Comment: And a page number?

Comment: On the version i have it's on page 50 from 8415.

Comment: Please move all comments into the question.  OP should not comment, but should edit the question to address the issues

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that [levels of evidence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_of_evidence) have mainly been relevant for the health sector, where mistakes in widely-published recommendations, guidelines etc. can easily cost thousands of lives. Of course history and archeology are not really risk-free either, but the connection to the respective outcomes is much more subtle. And there are usually less direct legal consequences for not following guidelines and the like.

I.e. medicine takes place (and has to take place) in a legal environment that is heavily regulated. History and archeology do not and do not have to. Under these conditions, ad-hoc verbal descriptions of the level of evidence ("it seems that ..., but we cannot be certain" etc) seem much more useful and are indeed very common in literature.

Comment: For example a significant percentage of young people and adults have difficulty making the difference between, for example: • A visual testimony from a single person and a meta-analysis • A primary source, a secondary source, a tertiary source • An account in a document written by a copyist of an original document • An opinion from a historian of a meta-analysis • A meta-analysis and systematic review • A blog of an article located in a peer-reviewed scientific journal in a high impact factor journal • etc…

Comment: @VincentISOZ I believe similar problems exist in health-related fields as well (e.g. recently people forming strong opinions on the usefulness of masks for preventing infections). So grading the robustness of the evidence might not be too useful in that regard.

Comment: I have a PhD in quantum chemistry and have never heard of these hierarchies of evidence. I suspect that they are more used by academics writing about physical science than by scientists. OTOH, there is a good consensus on what's good evidence -- no matter what the string theorists say! -- and it necessarily varies between disciplines. E.g., the discovery of the Higgs Boson (all about statistics) and the failure of recent room temperature superconductors (all about possessing or not possessing certain physical properties.) Reproducibility is not tidy, but it *is* effective.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a meaningful quantified measure that historians in general would recognize. [A nice little article by Carl Kaeste](https://www.jstor.org/stable/368550) explains this pretty well. Historians borrow criteria from other disciplines when, for example, they are looking at demographic statistics. More generally they try to correlate different forms of evidence, evaluate contradictory claims and so on. But given the nature of history as a discipline it is unreasonable to expect a direct parallel to the evidence criteria of hard sciences.